# Inserting date into MySQL database using a PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to update the string date into MySQL database using prepared statement. I have tried a lot and always got error `java.util.Date cannot parse  into java.sql.Date` or vise versa. I didn't import anything here. Please import according to your answer.

```
public class Date1 
{ 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        String source="2008/4/5";              
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                       
        java.sql.Date d=(Date) format.parse(source);             
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");        
        Connection con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee", "root", "root");   
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into ankur1 values(?)");          
        ps.setDate(1,(java.sql.Date) d);    
        ps.executUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you send details of ankur1 table

Comment: ` I didn't import anything here` -> Not even java.sql.Date??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write this

```
java.sql.Date d= new java.sql.Date(format.parse(source).getTime());
```

instead of this:

```
java.sql.Date d=(Date) format.parse(source);
```

Because you cannot just cast `java.util.Date` to its subtype `java.sql.Date`. You have to convert it. Do also note that your format string doesn't match your actual date format, as Bill the Lizard commented.

Comment: This is correct.  Also note that `"2008/4/5"` is not in the format `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Right, I didn't even notice

Comment: @Lukas Eder i have write your line you provided it is successfully reflected on a database like i have this                    String str = "2006-12-28";                                     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"); java.sql.Date d= new java.sql.Date(formatter.parse(str).getTime()); ps.setDate(1,d);       it is reflecting but whatever i have providing the data it is reflected as 01 in month place in each case in mysql 5.2.38

Comment: @ankurjadiya: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Do you have any other issues apart from what you had already mentioned in the question?

Comment: @LukasEder my question is that i have done what you had replied of my question its successful, i have mention  in my comment what i have write on java code, but the problem in mysql database different month is updating instead of what i provide in my java code for example i provide date 2006-09-28 in java program but in database it is updating like 2006-01-28 this is the problem  occuring please correct my code written in comment if there is any problem.

Comment: @ankur jadiya: Your Formatstring in your comment is wrong. Use "yyyy-MM-dd". So the months in uppercase. in lowercase (mm) they are ment for minutes.

Comment: @ankur jadiya: Please accept Lukas answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

pstmt.setTimestamp(1, date);
```

Try this it may work.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here is another simpler way to solve this:

```
preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test.TABLENAME VALUES (default, STR_TO_DATE( ?, '%m/%d/%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(?, '%l:%i %p'),?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Or, you can replace the "?" with real data.

This is how I insert date and time to mySQL, just figured it out.

We can adjust the kinds of parameters to meet our data's format, it's easy and clean.